# Is there such a thing as a persistent DOM in browser javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is a question for technicality sake, I am trying to learn more deeply about javascript in the browser.

So the scenario is that the only thing on page1 is a link and potentially some JS:

```
<script>something</script>
<a href="/page2.php">link</a>
```

When page 2 link is clicked, can some javascript be 'carried over' to page 2, such that JS can be run on page2 without it having any scripts originally in the markup?

I was thinking you could do something like:

```
<a onClick="loadXMLDoc();" href="/page2.php">link</a>
```

loadXMLDoc function excerpt:

```
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {

window.location = "/page2.php";

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
alert('worked');

}
...
xmlhttp.open("POST","/responsedelay.php",true);
...
```

The idea would be to make an ajax request to a separate page with a timer on it (in php), and after several seconds (say 10), given a response. By that time, the new page has loaded and we would hopefully still have javascript access to the current window DOM. ALAS, that didn't work, not too surprisingly, still trying to think outside the box! Any ideas?

I am guessing the only way would be to open page2 within the context of page1 (i.e add page 2 elements to page 1), but perhaps there is a novel way I am unaware of!

Comment: You might be interested in [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/), which just replaces the body element and leaves the page with all its JavaScript state still intact. I've never used it myself though.

Comment: If you're talking about actually leaving one page, and arriving at another, then no, the scripts need to be included in the page that will use them. But do you really need to load a new page? If you're making an XHR request, why not just update the existing page with the response?

Comment: Thanks fro your answers, I want to investigate the potential for persistent DOM access and how far it can be taken, not necessarily to speed up or make anything more efficient.

Comment: http is stateless , if you understand what it means then you know you are asking for something impossible.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't store JavaScript source in string form in local storage (other than to avoid being yelled at by JavaScript purists). However, the scenario described in the next-to-last paragraph - having an XHR request/response span page loads - is almost certainly not possible if you're talking about *real* page loads.

Comment: @Pointy , that's caching and has nothing to do with the question. Caching wont keep the current execution context.

Comment: @mpm yes I agree - I just added to that comment. If all that needs to be kept around is JavaScript code, and no global state, then local storage would work (though it seems pointless since the plain old browser cache will do that too).

Comment: @Pointy Can you clarify/cite any reading on what you mean by storing a string in local storage and how this applies to this research? thank you

Comment: Well if *all* you want is to avoid loading JavaScript, you *could* store it in local storage. However, that's kind-of pointless since basic browser caching would avoid reloading scripts anyway. And none of that would allow you to maintain global state across page reloads.

Comment: k thanks for all your insight, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context explains the basic concept quite well.

Whenever you load a page, either through the address bar, loading an `iframe` or like you mentioned through manipulating the [unique location object](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-location-interface) of the current pages' browsing context.

Simplified: If you change the location, your current pages DOM is thrown away (technically dereferenced and thus ready for garbage collection afaik in most engines) and replaced by the DOM built from the new location.

You can, however, keep the context and `window`, but switch parts of the DOM, which is pretty much everything beneath the `window`.

The [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) mentioned in a comment do exactly that: Keep the `window` object and context but replace the documents `body`.

Modern browser let you programatically change pretty much everything:

- The title of the current page.
- The content of the browser URL input field.
- The browser's history, so even back/forward buttons etc work (Mark Pilgrim wrote a [great piece on this](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) that should clarify further).

In short you could keep the same page, but for users it feels like they would browse around. YouTube is a good example for that: As you browse from video the video, the `window` is kept, but the `body`, parts of the header, the browsers URL and title etc are all changed.

The upside for YouTube is that they don't have to reload various video decoder libs etc for every single video you visit, but rather do it on your initial visit.

The downside is that you have to really know what you're doing, as bugs compound quickly and you easily break essential user flows (back button etc).